# BSOD while installing Intel HD 630 driver on windows 10 build 19041.329

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod, intel-graphics, intel-core-i7

I'm facing a problem to install the *Intel HD 630 driver* on my laptop. While installing, the screen becomes black and a BSOD came out. The problem is fixed when I disable the driver in device manager while in safe mode.

Because I did not install the *Intel HD driver*, I'm not able to control the brightness of the monitor. My laptop specification is as shown below:

- Model: MSI gl62m 7rex
- Processor: i7-7700HQ
- GPU: GTX1050TI
- RAM: 4GB

The error is:

> BSOD error: video_tdr_failure (igdkmd64.sys)

I thought that it was a Windows problem. So, I made a clean install to see if that fixes the problem or not. Unfortunately, it didn't fix it.

Comment: Since you just re-installed Windows, can you do so again and install the HP Video Driver for your specific machine?

Comment: My error - I thought it was a HP box. so then use the prior Intel Driver.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to install the proper device drivers.  [Intel® Graphics - Windows® 10 DCH Drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29616/Intel-Graphics-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers?v=t).  The driver in question supports `Windows 10 version 2004`.  Due to the state, your system currently is in, you might have to reinstall Windows 10 version 2004 and have the proper drivers handy.

Comment: I already tried the method as suggest above. It still cause black screen and bsod. It is possible my intel HD 630 hardware is the source of the problem. I mean the hardware is broken.